# What is the difference between .epf and .metadata

Tags: eclipse

I am new to eclipse and trying to back up my eclipse settings. I searched there are two ways to do this: export .epf file or copy the entire .metadata folder. Which one is preferred? What settings they save? Any differences between these two approaches?

Answer (score 3):

The `.epf` file just exports your preference settings (most of the things in the 'Preferences' dialog).

The `.metadata` folder also contains those preferences but it also contains lots of other data. Any plugin can put whatever data it wants in the metadata.

For example the `org.eclipse.core.resource` plugin keeps information about all the files in the workspace, `org.eclipse.jdt.core` keeps indices of all the Java source.

So it depends what you want to back up. If you just want to save your preferences use the `.epf` file. If you want a full backup then copy the entire workspace including the metadata.

I would strongly recommend that you backup your workspace regularly, I have seen too many questions here about people losing all their work with no backup!

Comment: I completely agree on backing up the complete workspace, because _there are_ many metadata stored in the individual projects (`.settings` folders) and not in the  `.metadata` folder.

Comment: ... Altough the safest practice would be working over a Source Control System.